# The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s)

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider, gtmetrix

I'm having an error I'm trying to fix but don't know how to:

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 107.8KiB.

https://cdn.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js.gzip?ver=5.4.8.3

https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?rev=5.4.8.3

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 63.4KiB.

https://cdn.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js.gzip?ver=5.4.8.3

https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?rev=5.4.8.3

Does anyone know how to fix it?